# Get table/column metadata from JOOQ parser result

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Using the JOOQ parser API, I'm able to parse the following query and get the parameters map from the resulting Query object.  From this, I can tell that there is one parameter, and it's name is "something".

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to determine that the parameter "something" is assigned to a column named "BAZ" and that column is part of the table "BAR".

Does the parser API have a way to get the table/column metadata associated to each parameter?

```
String sql = "SELECT A.FOO FROM BAR A WHERE A.BAZ = :something";

DSLContext context = DSL.using...
Parser parser = context.parser();
Query query = parser.parseQuery(sql);


Map<String, Param<?>> params = query.getParams();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Starting from jOOQ 3.16

jOOQ 3.16 introduced a new, experimental (as of 3.16) query object model API, which can be traversed, see:

- [The manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/model-api-traversal/)
- [A blog post about traversing jOOQ expression trees](https://blog.jooq.org/traversing-jooq-expression-trees-with-the-new-traverser-api/)

Specifically, you can write:

```java
List<QueryPart> parts = query.$traverse(
    Traversers.findingAll(q -> q instanceof Param)
);
```

Or, to conveniently produce exactly the type you wanted:

```java
Map<String, Param<?>> params = query.$traverse(Traversers.collecting(
    Collectors.filtering(q -> q instanceof Param,
        Collectors.toMap(
            q -> ((Param<?>) q).getParamName(),
            q -> (Param<?>) q
        )
    )
));
```

The `Collectors.toMap()` call could include a `mergeFunction`, in case you have the same param name twice.

#### Pre jOOQ 3.16

As of jOOQ 3.11, the SPI that can be used to access the internal expression tree is the [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) SPI, which you have to attach to your `context.configuration()` prior to parsing. It will then be invoked whenever you traverse that expression tree, e.g. on your `query.getParams()` call.

However, there's quite a bit of manual plumbing that needs to be done. For example, the `VisitListener` will only see `A.BAZ` as a column reference without knowing directly that `A` is the renamed table `BAR`. You will have to keep track of such renaming yourself when you visit the `BAR A` expression.