# How to use JOOQ's parser to extract table names from SQL statements

Tags: java, sql, parsing, kotlin, jooq

I'm trying to parse SQL statements and extract table names using JOOQ's [parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/). The problem is, the Query and SelectQuery don't seem to provide a public getter for the parsed table list.

```
    val parser = DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10).parser()
    val queries = parser.parse("SELECT foo, bar FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;")
    for (query in queries) {
        when (query) {
            is SelectQuery<*> -> println(query.fields().map { it.name }) // can find the fields, but not the tables
            else -> println(query)
        }        
    }
```

I could indeed help myself accessing the private field using reflection, but I wonder if there is an easier way:

```
    val field = query.javaClass.getDeclaredField("from")
    field.isAccessible = true
    println(field.get(query))
```

And of course, this should also work for other statements (e.g. Insert, update, delete).

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55355879/521799, https://stackoverflow.com/q/53696181/521799. Note, we're working on an improvement of our internal APIs, but we're not there yet.

Comment: ... what's your use case for extracting the table? Would love to hear it. Maybe on the mailing list? https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jooq-user